# passing parameters through hashmap to function in java

Tags: java

i was trying to build a command line tool alike in java, for example, if i write down in console "dir c:/....", it will activate my Dir class and will get the "c:/...." path as a parameter to the Dir class, and doing so with hashmap.

i dont know how to pass parameters through the commandline and hashmap,
is it even possible?

every command has it's own class, which implements the main "Command" interface, with a doCommand() function.

after running the start() function in the CLI class, it should take commands and do the requested command.

Command Interface:

```
public interface Command {
   public void doCommand();
}
```

my CLI class:

```
public class CLI {

BufferedReader in;
PrintWriter out;

HashMap<String, Command> hashMap;
Controller controller;

public CLI(Controller controller, BufferedReader in, PrintWriter out,
        HashMap<String, Command> hashMap) {
    this.in = in;
    this.out = out;
    this.hashMap = hashMap;
}

public void start() {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                out.println("Enter a command please:");
                String string = in.readLine();
                while (!string.equals("exit")) {
                    Command command = hashMap.get(string);
                    command.doCommand();

                    string = in.readLine();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
}
```

lets take for example my DirCommmand, as i said before, which should recognize the "dir" string through my hashMap configuration, and should pass the next word as a string parameter for the path

```
public class DirCommand implements Command {

@Override
public void doCommand() {
    System.out.println("doing dir command...");

}
```

}

and my hashmap configuration:

```
    hashMap.put("dir", new DirCommand());
```

which sets in a diffrent class the hashMap configuration and pass it to the CLI class's hashMap object at the start of the project.

i would love for some help because i have no idea how to do so.

Comment: Any reason why you listed your `CLI` class twice?

Comment: you were right, i added this twice by mistake. i fixed the Dir class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in order to pass the parameters to **doCommand**, what I would do is use a variable param list, like:

```
public interface Command {
    public void doCommand(String... params);
}
```

Second, I would split the input string on spaces as:

```
String[] result = command.split(" ");
```

Finally, the command would be the **result[0]** and the rest you would pass to the **doCommand** method.

Comment: i've thought of that, but i thought there would be a simplier solution to this problem, maybe a built in solution in the hash map object. thank you for your answer, but i'll wait maybe there is a simplier solution then this :)

Comment: In your current design I bet that's the simpler solution. I would suggest you to take a look at the **Command** design pattern. There are lots of implementations out there. Maybe they are more complicated, but more robust as well, depending on your problem.